# 'autoComplete' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using Typescript with React and am getting this error:

```
Property 'autoComplete' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps'.
```

I am using the component like this:

```
        <Input
          value={email}
          id="email"
          type="email"
          label="email"
          autoComplete="email"
          placeholder="Joe@hotmail.com"
          handleChange={event => setName(event.target.value)}
        />
```

The Typescript for the props is defined like this:

```
type InputProps = {
  label: string;
  id: string;
  type?: "text" | "email" | "date" | "number" | "tel";
  helptext?: string;
  handleChange: (event) => void;
  value?: any;
  validationMessage?: string[] | string;
  validationType?:
    | "help"
    | "info"
    | "invalid"
    | "valid"
    | "validating"
    | "warning";
  otherProps: any;
};
```

Any excess HTML attributes are passed through with otherProps.

```
function Input({
  value = "",
  type = "text",
  handleChange,
  label,
  id,
  helptext,
  validationMessage,
  validationType,
  ...otherProps
}: InputProps) {
```

Then the otherProps are put on the input:

```
 <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} type={type} id={id} {...otherProps} />
```

Comment: Where is the `Input` component coming from? and, do u have control over `type InputProps` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>` has all the correct type information for the props available on `<input>`. You could extend your `InputProps` with this type and the `autoComplete` prop will then be available with the correct type information.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working with ```function Input({
  value = "",
  type = "text",
  handleChange,
  label,
  id,
  helptext,
  validationMessage,
  validationType,
  ...otherProps
}: InputProps & React.InputHTMLAttributes) {```